# What is \ufeed?

Tags: java, escaping

I was reading my lecture note and came across a certain escape character in java known as `'\ufeed'`. What is this character used for and what it is displayed as? Thank you.

Comment: It's the Unicode character at code point `FE ED` (this is a hexadecimal number that happens to spell an English word).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Charbase](http://www.charbase.com/feed-unicode-arabic-letter-waw-isolated-form), its the Arabic letter "WAW" isolated form. It's displayed as `ﻭ`